# When putting a string in preferences, it doesn't change. Any ideas why?

Tags: java, registry, preferences

```
String path = workspaceField.getText();

        //prefs.remove("workspaceDirectory");
        prefs.put("workspaceDirectory", path); 

        splitPane = commands.getSplitPane();
        WebScrollPane oldTree = (WebScrollPane) splitPane.getLeftComponent();
        splitPane.remove(oldTree);

        WebScrollPane newTree = commands.createFileTree();
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(newTree);
        dialog.dispose();
```

The above code gets a file path from a text field, then puts that in a String preference called "workspaceDirectory". The issue is that that preference does not change. The commented prefs.remove call removes the preference successfully, but it doesn't change the preference when prefs.put("workspaceDirectory", path) is called. I don't receive any errors.

The method createFileTree():

```
public WebScrollPane createFileTree() {
    fileTree = new WebFileTree(prefs.get("workspaceDirectory", WorkspaceManager.createWorkspaceDirectory()));
    fileTreeScrollPane = new WebScrollPane(fileTree);   
    fileTreeScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(WebScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    fileTree.addMouseListener(new FileTreeListener(this));
    return fileTreeScrollPane;
}
```

That's all createFileTree does, but it doesn't affect anything. If I comment the code out that changes the components, prefs.put does nothing. Any ideas what causes this or is stopping the preference from being changed?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the javadoc for `java.util.Preferences`:

> All of the methods that modify preferences data are permitted to operate asynchronously; they may return immediately, and changes will eventually propagate to the persistent backing store with an implementation-dependent delay. The flush method may be used to synchronously force updates to the backing store. Normal termination of the Java Virtual Machine will not result in the loss of pending updates -- an explicit flush invocation is not required upon termination to ensure that pending updates are made persistent.

So, if you make a change to the preferences and then immediately try to read that change, your results may not be what you would expect.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank-you. I just threw in a System.exit(0) right after prefs.put and when I checked the registry it was changed. So how would I come about making this preference change immediate?

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. I've gotten it figured out.